# How to specify the row index when I want to append the specified data in a specified row and column (lowagie)

Tags: java

I am currently using the `com.lowagie` to generate all my record into a pdf file. Then I want to add certain data in a specify row and column. How to do this? My code shown below is fail.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XU6Dl.png) - My desired output will be like the table in the picture when I generate the table in the pdf file.

```
 for(int i =0; i<AcademicSystem.allStdInfo.size();i++){
                    Student std = AcademicSystem.allStdInfo.get(i);
                    Cell c1 = new Cell(std.getName());
                    Cell c2 = new Cell(std.getGender());
                    t.addCell(c1,0,i);
                }
```

Comment: Looks like you are using the old, deprecated version of the [library](https://www.lowagie.com/iText).

Comment: @Abra this was my school assignment, my teacher instruct me to use this old version, I also curios why not use the iText instead